# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'subscribe')

Tags: robotwebtools

I am trying to visualize a robot on web. I tried to use the `urdf.html` example of the `roslibjs`. I have successfully connected to the ros server via rosbridge_websocket, as the `Connected` showed up in Green. When I read the browser console, I can see: THREE.WebGRLenderer 89; Connection made!; and UrdfModel. There, when I go into the details of the UrdfModle, it was the correct urdf.
But then it has: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'subscribe').
The source of my `urdf.html` is like the following:

````
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<!-- 
<script src="../build/roslib.js"></script>
-->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.89.0/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/roslib@1/build/roslib.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/ros3d.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/ColladaLoader.js') }}"></script>
<script>
  /**
   * Setup all visualization elements when the page is loaded.
   */

   // Create a URDF model variable in a broader scope
   var urdfModel;

   function init() {
    // Connect to ROS.
    var ros = new ROSLIB.Ros({
      url : 'ws://localhost:9090'
    });

    // If there is an error on the backend, an 'error' emit will be emitted.
    ros.on('error', function(error) {
      document.getElementById('connecting').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('connected').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('closed').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('error').style.display = 'inline';
      console.log(error);
    });

    // Find out exactly when we made a connection.
    ros.on('connection', function() {
      console.log('Connection made!');
      document.getElementById('connecting').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('error').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('closed').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('connected').style.display = 'inline';
    });

    ros.on('close', function() {
      console.log('Connection closed.');
      document.getElementById('connecting').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('connected').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('closed').style.display = 'inline';
    });

    // Get the URDF value from ROS.
    var param = new ROSLIB.Param({
      ros : ros,
      name : 'robot_description'
    });

    // Create the main viewer
    var viewer = new ROS3D.Viewer({
      divID: 'URDF', // ID of the div where the URDF will be shown
      width: 800,
      height: 600,
      antialias: true,
      // background: '#ffffff',
    });

    // Add a grid
    viewer.addObject(new ROS3D.Grid());

    // Get the URDF value from ROS
    var param = new ROSLIB.Param({
      ros: ros,
      name: 'robot_description'
    });

    // Setup a client to listen to TFs.
    var tfClient = new ROSLIB.TFClient({
      ros : ros,
      angularThres : 0.01,
      transThres : 0.01,
      rate : 10.0
    });

    param.get(function(param){
      // Setup the loader for the URDF.
      urdfModel = new ROSLIB.UrdfModel({
        string: param
      });

      console.log(urdfModel);

      // Setup the URDF client to display the model
      var urdfClient = new ROS3D.UrdfClient({
        ros: ros,
        urdfText: param,
        path: 'http://localhost:8080/static',
        urdfModel: urdfModel,
      });
    })
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="init()">
  <h1>Simple URDF Parsing Example</h1>

  <p>Run the following commands in the terminal then refresh this page. Check the JavaScript
    console for the output.</p>
  <ol>
    <li><tt>roslaunch pr2_description upload_pr2.launch</tt></li>
    <li><tt>roslaunch rosbridge_server rosbridge_websocket.launch</tt></li>
  </ol>
  <div id="URDF"></div>
  <div id="statusIndicator">
    <p id="connecting">
      Connecting to rosbridge...
    </p>
    <p id="connected" style="color:#00D600; display:none">
      Connected
    </p>
    <p id="error" style="color:#FF0000; display:none">
      Error in the backend!
    </p>
    <p id="closed" style="display:none">
      Connection closed.
    </p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```
````